# Jstree lazy loading using Socket IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have seen lazy loading using request response of jquery ajax but isn't there any way I can load the node data lazily using Socket IO? For example I want something like this

```
$("#tree").jstree({
      "core": {
          "data": function(data){
            socket.on("node",function(node){
              data = node;
            })
          }
       }
    });
```

And on each click I would be able to call the data callback to set the node. Any thoughts on that? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Do you mean WebSocket?

Comment: Sorry I am using [Socket IO](http://socket.io/)

Comment: I think your approach is just right. And there should be a `var socket = io("http://xxxxx")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Socket IO but i'm sure you're not doing it right with jstree : here is what your function should look like :

```
function(currentNode, callback){
        //we got it called twice, prolly because of angular
        if(currentNode.id=='#'){
            var me = this;
            // perform a request with your framework here and call this once you have your data, '#' mean we're loading the root nodes
            var nodes = <your data>  
            callback.call(me, nodes);
        }else{
           var me = this;
           // we're loading child nodes
           // same as before ask the nodes to the server then call the callback with the data loaded.
           var nodes = <your data>
           callback.call(me, nodes)
       }
```

}

Note : "this" is the tree instance.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://xxxx.xx/xxx/");
ws.onopen = function () {
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        $("#codeeditor").jstree({
            "core": {
                "data": {
                    "data": function(data){
                         data = evt.data;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Also some approach to keep the WebSocket connected all along is needed, which I didn't show here.

Comment: @essaji Sorry. I'm going to have a look. 